# Connection Leak with Spring boot jpa and stored procedure

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, hikaricp

I'm using Spring JPA in Spring-boot(2.1.5) and HikariCP connection pool in the project.

I have a stored procedure(@Procedure) query. The proc gets invoked each request.

With @Transactional annotation, it is working fine but without the @Transactional annotated over my repository interface/method, the connection in the connection pool runs out. I am getting "Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 30 seconds, none available[size:100; busy:100; idle:0; lastwait:30000]."